# How do "wait" and "notify" work for std::atomic in C++20?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, thread-synchronization, stdatomic

C++20 added `std::atomic`-based thread synchronization methods using wait (`std::atomic::wait`) and notify ([`std::atomic::notify_one`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/notify_one) or [`std::atomic::notify_all`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/notify_all)) functions for them. The link https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/performancecomparison-of-condition-variables-and-atomics-in-c-20 provides examples of using two variables of type [`std::atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) to transfer control between two threads ("ping-pong game"). Here is the original code for this example (variant "Two Atomic Flags"):

```
// pingPongAtomicFlags.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

std::atomic_flag condAtomicFlag1{};
std::atomic_flag condAtomicFlag2{};

std::atomic<int> counter{};
constexpr int countlimit = 1'000'000;

void ping() {
    while(counter <= countlimit) {
        condAtomicFlag1.wait(false);               // (1)
        condAtomicFlag1.clear();                   // (2)

        ++counter;
        
        condAtomicFlag2.test_and_set();           // (4)
        condAtomicFlag2.notify_one();             // (3)
    }
}

void pong() {
    while(counter < countlimit) {
        condAtomicFlag2.wait(false);
        condAtomicFlag2.clear();
        
        condAtomicFlag1.test_and_set();
        condAtomicFlag1.notify_one();
    }
}

int main() {
     auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();  

    condAtomicFlag1.test_and_set();                    // (5)
    std::thread t1(ping);
    std::thread t2(pong);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::chrono::duration<double> dur = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << dur.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
}
```

I changed this code a bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::atomic_flag condAtomicFlag1{};
std::atomic_flag condAtomicFlag2{};

std::atomic<int> counter{};
constexpr int countlimit = 2;

auto time() {
  static auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
}

void ping() {
    while(counter <= countlimit) {
        condAtomicFlag1.wait(false);               // (1)
        condAtomicFlag1.clear();                   // (2)
        std::cout << time() << " sec: ping() flag1" << std::endl;
        
        ++counter;

        condAtomicFlag2.test_and_set();           // (4)
        condAtomicFlag2.notify_one();             // (3)
    }
}

void pong() {
    while(counter <= countlimit) {
        condAtomicFlag2.wait(false);
        condAtomicFlag2.clear();
        std::cout << time() << " sec: pong() flag2" << std::endl;
        
        condAtomicFlag1.test_and_set();
        condAtomicFlag1.notify_one();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::cout << time() << " sec: before pong() flag2" << std::endl;
  std::thread t2(pong);
  std::cout << time() << " sec: after pong() flag2" << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
  condAtomicFlag1.test_and_set();                    // (5)
  std::cout << time() << " sec: flag1 test and set" << std::endl;
  //condAtomicFlag1.notify_one();                      // (6)
  //std::cout << time() << " sec: flag1 notify_one" << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
  std::cout << time() << " sec: before ping() flag1" << std::endl;
  std::thread t1(ping);
  std::cout << time() << " sec: after ping() flag1" << std::endl;

  t1.join();
  t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Now, at first, only the `t2` (pong) thread is started, in which there is a waiting of a change in the state of the atomic flag `condAtomicFlag2`. Then the main thread goes to sleep for 3 seconds. After that, the state of the atomic flag `condAtomicFlag1` (`test_and_set`) changes, although the thread waiting for it has not been started yet. Then the main thread goes to sleep again for 3 seconds. Finally, thread `t1` (ping) is started, in which there is a waiting of a change in the state of the atomic flag `condAtomicFlag1`. Since earlier `condAtomicFlag1` was already changed to `true` when calling `condAtomicFlag1.test_and_set()`, the `t1` thread immediately starts working and the transfer of control from the `t1` thread to the `t2` thread and back starts a number of times (`countlimit + 1`). The application output looks pretty predictable to me:

```
0 sec: before pong() flag2
0 sec: after pong() flag2
3 sec: flag1 test and set
6 sec: before ping() flag1
6 sec: after ping() flag1
6 sec: ping() flag1
6 sec: pong() flag2
6 sec: ping() flag1
6 sec: pong() flag2
6 sec: ping() flag1
6 sec: pong() flag2
```

But now I will uncomment two lines in the code of the main function:

```
condAtomicFlag1.notify_one();                      // (6)
  std::cout << time() << " sec: flag1 notify_one" << std::endl;
```

I figured this was just a notification to the waiting thread that the state of the `condAtomicFlag1` atomic flag has changed. And since we have not yet started a thread that will wait for this particular flag, nothing interesting will happen. But I got this application output:

```
0 sec: before pong() flag2
0 sec: after pong() flag2
3 sec: flag1 test and set
3 sec: flag1 notify_one
3 sec: pong() flag2
6 sec: before ping() flag1
6 sec: after ping() flag1
6 sec: ping() flag1
6 sec: pong() flag2
6 sec: ping() flag1
6 sec: pong() flag2
6 sec: ping() flag1
6 sec: pong() flag2
```

Here you can see that on the 3rd second after calling `condAtomicFlag1.notify_one()`,

> 3 sec: flag1 notify_one

for some reason, thread `t2` exited waiting in the `condAtomicFlag2.wait(false)` function,

> 3 sec: pong() flag2

that is, in fact, it waited until the state of the atomic flag `condAtomicFlag2` changed. But how could `condAtomicFlag1.notify_one()` affect the wait for a completely different flag in `condAtomicFlag2.wait(false)`?

About [`std::atomic::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait) it is written that *"These functions are guaranteed to return only if value has changed, even if underlying implementation unblocks spuriously"*. That is, the return from the function is carried out only when the value changes, even in the case of a false unlock. But I do not see any changes to `condAtomicFlag2` in my case, and the return from the function is still carried out?

It looks like I do not understand something in the work of the wait-notify bundle? Explain to me what is happening here and why the notification of one flag affects the state of the other?

P.S. For the project I used the gcc compiler version 11.1.0 (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1 ~ 20.04)

Comment: Seems fixed with gcc 11.2.0 [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bnW9n1fY6)

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qMcq8Ph99) which prints value of `condAtomicFlag2` with `0` for the problematic case.

Comment: @Jarod42, you seem to be right. Apparently it was a bug in libstdc++ in gcc-11.1. In gcc-11.2 it has already been fixed.